# How to get these CLion unit tests in C to pass?

Tags: c, unit-testing, googletest, clion

I am looking to fix a CLion library project (C language) with unit tests passing. Although I'm using [Googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest) but I'm running into compilation problems. It says:

> Can't resolve type 'ASSERT_EQ'

My code is below:

#### `arithmetic.h`

```
#ifndef MATH_LIBRARY_H
#define MATH_LIBRARY_H

int add(int a, int b);
int sub(int a, int b);
int mul(int a, int b);

#endif
```

#### `arithmetic.c`

```
#include "arithmetic.h"

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int sub(int a, int b) {
    return a - b;
}

int mul(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

#### `tests.c`

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <arithmetic.h>
#include "tests.h"

TEST(SuiteName, TestName) {
    ASSERT_EQ(add(1, 1), 2); // Can't resolve type 'ASSERT_EQ'
}
```

Comment: I've done some edits, hopefully it's fixed, alternatively here's the download link. https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsknk09fyuozwpw/Math.zip?dl=0

Comment: i mean it involves perhaps configuration settings to look at, so besides copying code on the question, I've uploaded the project as well in case one wants to see whole project, configuration and settings. I'm new to unit testing in C. i've fixed the issue.

Comment: Using a private header `math.h` is a very bad idea. Don’t!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, sure I'm new to C, how can I mark it public and also any advice on the unit testing part.

Comment: What I mean is that there is a standard header `<math.h>` so you should not create your own header with the name `math.h`.  The behaviour of your program is undefined.  Use a different header name. For what you show, `arith.h` or `arithmetic.h` might be appropriate.

Comment: done. hopefully if i can provide a solution for unit test example

Comment: any idea on ASSERT_EQ problem?

Comment: I have removed a 404 link containing the project. I am not sure whether the remaining question is sufficiently self-contained to remain open, or whether it now lacks a [mcve]. @JonathanLeffler, could you take a view on that?

Comment: @halfer: Thanks for the edit.  The code in the question looks to be complete apart from the material provided by Googletest, and that isn't strictly needed (and is far too big to be included in the question anyway).  I (still) don't have a good answer for why the `ASSERT_EQ` is missing.

Comment: Great, thanks @Jonathan. No worries, just doing some question-pruning.